# How to write mathematical ODE equation of PI controller, with saturation and rate limiter in differential equation form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, mathematical-modeling

I want to write a mathematical ODE equation of PI controller, with saturation and rate limiter in differential equation form. I can write PI controller, but how to incorporate it with saturation and rate limiter?

```
du/dt = Wt_rated - wt; 
B_ref = Kp *(Wt_rated - wt) + Ki *u
```

Please see the attached photograph.
[image: PI Controller with saturation and rate limiter].

Comment: They are nonlinear functions. You describe them using the if/else statements (cases) of the $\operatorname{sat}$ function.

Comment: @Arastas There is no **sat** inbuilt function in MATLAB. Another thing is **sat** is for saturation through if/else, but how can I do for rate limiter?

Comment: For the rate limiter, you bound the derivative. Or, in the discrete-time setup, the one-step difference.

Comment: @Arastas kindly share any simple code related that. Thanks